Was heißt hier 'Basisverb'?
Folgendes habe ich neulich in einer Dissertation über Partikelverben gefunden:

Sofern das Basisverb ein Partizip II mit dem Flexiv 'ge-' bildet, wird dieses zwischen Partikel und Basisverb eingefügt.

Aber: ist bei z.B. 'abnehmen' als Basisverb die Infinitivform 'nehmen' zu verstehen, so ergibt sich 'ab-ge-nehmen'. Ist "Basisverb" als "Partizip des Basisverbs" zu verstehen, so ergibt sich 'ab-ge-genommen'. Bei 'abgenommen' befindet sich 'ge-' zwischen 'ab' und 'nommen', das als Basisverb kaum in Frage kommt. Die gleichen Probleme tauchen übrigens auch bei schwachen Verben auf.

Gemeint ist wohl, dass es "abgenommen" heisst und nicht etwa "geabnommen"

Mit Basisverb ist offensichtlich das Verb ohne Partikel gemeint, nicht eine Verbform wie das Partizip.
Im vorliegenden Beispiel ist also nehmen das Basisverb, von dem ausgehend ds Verb abnehmen gebildet wird.
Nehmen bildet das Partizip II genommen. Das Partizip von abnehmen wird aus dem Präfix ge-, dem Partikel ab und dem Verb nehmen gebildet, das die starke Form -nommen angenommen hat, woraus sich abgenommen ergibt.

Aber ohne ge- existiert "nommen" überhaupt nicht!

"Basisverb" bezieht sich auf eine morphologische Basis (Basis einer Anfügung), die verbal ist. Gemeint ist hier wohl die Basis der Partikelverb-Bildung; das ist auch irgendein Wortbildungsvorgang, auch wenn der genaue Typ obskur ist. Der Infinitiv auf -en ist eine Flexionsform, die Partizipbildung in vielen Fällen auch, sie ist oft eine Variante des Infinitivs (sog. 3. Status des Infinitivs). Diese Infinitivformen konkurrieren miteinander, sie werden nie miteinander verbunden wie in deiner Frage. (Zu einem Fall von Konkurrenz und Austauschbarkeit siehe das Stichwort "Ersatzinfinitiv").
Gemeint ist mit Basisverb also zunächst der Verbstamm, im Unterschied zum Verb in der Zitierform (das ist die Form, die dich an den Infinitiv denken lässt). Siehe auch https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundform_(Grammatik) und https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wortstamm#Stamm_und_Basis
Beispiel: "einfügen" hat als relevanten Wortstamm "füg" – Partizipform/3. Infinitiv "ge-füg-t" - Partikelverb in der Form, wo Partizip verlangt ist: "ein + gefügt".
Falls man sagt, dass die Partizipform auch eine Flexionsform ist, ist das für das Partikelverb schon in Ordnung, das zeigt dann nur, dass die Partikelverb-Bildung ein besonderer, teilweise syntaktischer Prozess ist: Die Partikel kombiniert sich mit einer flektierten Form und kann von dieser auch getrennt vorkommen (Klassiker...).
Siehe auch https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partikelverb#Wortstruktur_der_deutschen_Partikelverben

Die zitierte Regel ist also irreführend; 'ge-' wird nicht in etwas hineingeschoben, sondern die Partikel wird einfach an das Partizip angeschrieben: ab + genommen = abgenommen

@Georg Das kann man so oder so sehen.

Warum aber nicht die einfachere Methode benutzen, die auch den Vorteil hat, die historische Entstehung solcher Formen zu widerspiegeln?
